# Rubygems: How do I add platform-specific dependency?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've [a ruby gem](https://github.com/mockko/livereload/tree/master/server) that has different dependencies for each OS. I have to explicitly write all of them down:

> On Mac OS X:
>
> ```
> gem install livereload
> ```
>
> on Linux:
>
> ```
> gem install rb-inotify livereload
> ```
>
> on Windows:
>
> ```
> gem install eventmachine-win32 win32-changenotify win32-event livereload
> ```

Can I tweak a gemspec a bit so installation instructions would look like plain `gem install livereload` for every OS?

Comment: It seems to be a good idea to check how [listen](https://github.com/guard/listen) gem handles its platform-specific dependencies: [rb-inotify](https://github.com/nex3/rb-inotify) and [rb-fsevent](https://github.com/thibaudgg/rb-fsevent).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The proper way to do this is outlined [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/RubyGems#How_to_install_different_versions_of_gems_depending_on_which_version_of_ruby_the_installee_is_using). Since the gemspec is evaluated at package time, you need to do it in a native extension. Don't worry, it's not that scary since its still just Ruby code (not compiling C or anything).

We are currently using this approach for some client tools for OpenShift [(source)](https://github.com/openshift/os-client-tools/blob/master/express/ext/mkrf_conf.rb). Then in your gemspec/Rakefile, instead of adding dependencies, you would add an extension. Note that the file needs to be named `ext/mkrf_conf.rb` for this to work.

Comment: Your source-link does not work. Also: would it not be possible to simply add all gems as dependencies in the Gemspec, and require them based on platform? (`require 'gemname' if RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /freebsd/i`)

Comment: @Cort3z you are missing one important point. The solution that you describe works, but it solves the problem of **not using** the gem dependency for certain OS after it is installed. The original problem is **not installing** the dependency at all.

Comment: Here's my example. I have a set of tools developed in-house that combine a number os shell and ruby scripts that we use for iOS, Android developemtn and other tasks. It's all wrapped into a Ruby gem. For iOS we have dependencies like _xcodeproj_, _cocoapods_, _calabash-cucumber_. These gems won't install on any OS other than OSX, simply because they need Xcode command line tools, iOS simulator and other things. 

But I still want to be able to install the gem on Linux to use Android scripts. I will not use any iOS tools on Linux, but it is also important that those are not installed.

Comment: I could, of course, have 2 versions of the gem built, one for OSX, and one for the rest. But I like more the idea of having on gem on the gem server.