# Is there any way of easily refreshing a website coded in G(Vim)?

Tags: vim, browser

I realized that I waste 10% of my time changing windows between Vim and Firefox.

```
Alt + Tab + F5 (and sometimes a get the wrong window).
```

Is there a way of making this task easier?

I thought of the following:

- Embending vim to firefox (I think it is impossible).
- Making a Vim shortcut which sends me to Firefox's window.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, I guess this ain't proper answer, but You might benefit from these tools.

For Chrome - try [LiveReload](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei).
For Firefox - try [XRefresh](http://xrefresh.binaryage.com/).

Comment: @alexchenco I'm pretty sure they both work on ubuntu. Have seen them working on OSX and used LiveReload on ubuntu myself.

Comment: @Arnis L. Could You write how You did this on Ubuntu? I'm trying for a while but without success.

Comment: Got it working! Just type in the terminal: "gem install rb-inotify livereload" Insiration from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596606/rubygems-how-do-i-add-platform-specific-dependency

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Vim shortcut to open the current file in Firefox. It should work on Ubuntu, though I'm not in front of my Linux machine to test. You can add it to your `~/.vimrc`

```
map <Leader>p :!firefox %<CR><CR> " Preview the current html file in Firefox
```

If you're looking for varations on that same theme, there are quite a few similar tips on the [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip127). Check the duplicate links tip at the top and the "See Also" links at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is a good free option.

You could assign a key combination to activate the Firefox browser, send the F5 key to Firefox, and then return focus to Vim.

Benefits of AutoHotKey:

- You could have logic that checks whether the Firefox is open, and if it is not open, open it.
- You could use the AutoHotKey Window Spy tool to actually activate Firefox. Alt+Tab will fail if you've activated another window in between Vim and Firefox.

See for example:

- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinActivate.htm
- http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm