# How to remove another gem with my gemspec

Tags: ruby, rubygems

We have a gem `foo` that used to have a dependency on another of our gems `bar`. But now we've pulled the `bar` code directly into `foo`.

Is it possible to have the `bar` gem removed the next time our users upgrade `foo`?

Comment: you may want to accept some answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found a quick and dirty solution, similar to [adding conditional install time deps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249133/309514). Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to tell the user, since `gem` squashes the extension output unless the user specifies verbose.

in the ext/mkrf_conf.rb, I added:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rubygems/uninstaller.rb'
begin
  gem = Gem::Specification.find_by_name('other_gem');
  Gem::Uninstaller.new('other_gem').uninstall
rescue Gem::LoadError
end
```